# Building sequence data for a recommender system- replacing cross-tabular matrix with a variable value

Tags: r, sequence, crosstab, sequences, recommendation-engine

I am trying to build a sequence data for a recommender system. I have built a cross-tabular data (Table 1) and Table 2 as shown below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HbKh.jpg)

I have been trying to replace all the 1's in Table 1 by the "Grade" from the Table 2 in R.

Any insight/suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replacing the first one with second, the second table and directly changed to 'wide' with `dcast`

```
library(reshape2)
res <- dcast(df2, St.No. ~ Courses, value.var = 'Grade')[names(df1)]
res
#    St.No. Math Phys Chem CS
#1      1         A       B
#2      2         B    B   
#3      3    A         A  C
#4      4    B    B       D
```

If we need to replace the blanks with 0

```
res[res =='"] <- "0"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(St.No. = 1:4, Math = c(0, 0, 1, 1), Phys = c(1, 1, 0, 1),
        Chem = c(0, 1, 1, 0), CS = c(1, 0, 1, 1))

df2 <- data.frame(St.No. = rep(1:4, each = 4), Courses = rep(c("Math", 
      "Phys", "Chem", "CS"), 4),
                Grade = c("", "A", "", "B", "", "B", "B", "", 
      "A", "", "A", "C", "B", "B", "", "D"),
           stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you, Akrun. I tried the code and I got the following warning: Aggregate function missing: default to length                                          In addition, I still see 1's instead of "Grade". Any other approach to this?

Comment: @JayanthNBharadwaj  Is this based on the same data (i provided the data)?  I don't get the error in this data.  May be in your original data, here are dupes, you need to create a sequence by group column to avoid that warning

Comment: Yeah, it worked. There were duplicates in St. No. and as a result, df1 had '2' too. Thank you, Akrun!